# Strange onPause / onResume / onPause sequence when launching intent

Tags: android, onresume, onpause

I am attempting to launch a new Acivity using an intent on top of another activity.  I have the android:launchMode set to singleTask because I only want a single instance of this to be going on.  When I launch the activity, the underlying activity's lifecycle methods fire like this, in rapid succession:

```
onPause()
onResume()
onPause()
```

I've searched around quite a while without finding a solution.  Has anyone seen anything similar?

I am launching the intent using startActivityForResult.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android


This might help you...

Comment: Well, I have found the "what" but not the "why" - I was starting my activity with startActivityForResult.  Switching this to startActivity (I don't use the result, so I don't know why I used this in the first place) made the onPause/onResume of the underlying activity behave correctly.